# How can I code to retrieve records when using this complicated doubled association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models such as `User` and `Tracking`

`Tracking` models has these 6 columns below

- id
- user_id
- target_user_id
- accessed_at
- created_at
- updated_at

The objective for this model is to know who accessed to my `users/show.html.erb` page.

Each user wants to know who looked at my page.

How can I make associations in both `User` and `Tracking` model?

Is it something like this?

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many: trackings
```

**models/tracking.rb**

```
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: user, :foreign_key => "target_user_id", :class_name => "TargetUser"
```

After all,
`current_user.tracking.target_user` shows the user whom the current_user accessed?

Then how can I retrieve the tracking records who accessed to current_user's?
How can I code in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your project there is no class with name "TargetUser",
**:class_name** option is to specify the name of the model you want to set association

in **models/tracking.rb** change your code like this,

```
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: target_user, :foreign_key => "target_user_id", :class_name => "User"
```

then you can access user from tracking by tracking.target_user

Comment: since tracing user is also a user, you can go for self association, for more details check the link http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `accessed_at` column is redundant, you can simply delegate it like this:

```
delegate :accessed_at, to: :created_at
```

**models/tracking.rb**

```
belongs_to: tracked_user, foreign_key:  'target_user_id', class_name: 'User'
```

Then traverse it:

```
current_user.trackings.each do |t|
  puts t.tracked_user_id
end
```